# Register Src attribute and block c# code within asp.net webform page

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms, user-controls

I have created this helper :

```
   public static class UrlHelper
    {

        public static string  SharedFolderUrl = "/template/";
        public static string  SpecificFolderSiteUrl = "/static/";

        public static string GetSharedFileUrl(this System.Web.UI.Control control, string fileurl)
        {
            return control.ResolveUrl(string.Concat(
                SharedFolderUrl,
                fileurl,
                string.Concat((fileurl.Contains("?") ? "&v=" : "?v="), _SiteVersion)
            ).Replace("//", "/"));
        }

}
```

So , in the home master page I tried to change this line :

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="mscom" TagName="Wedcs" Src="/template/Wedcs.ascx" %>
```

by :

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="mscom" TagName="Wedcs" Src="<%$ this.GetSharedFileUrl("controls/tracking/Wedcs.ascx")%>" %>
```

I have an error indicates that the format of this line is not correct.

I need to know how can I fix this issue?

Thanks,

Comment: It is not the same problem, my extension methode is accessible but the "Src" attribute doesn't accept a c# code

Comment: Answer is you cannot do that. What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is called ***VirtualPathProvider***.

The concept is we could move `aspx` and `ascx` files outside of traditional folder, and find and render them dynamically. *For example, store those in SQL Database or Azure Blob Storage.*

ASP.NET Web Form is very mature technology, and you could easily google how to implement VirtualPathProvider.

Answer (score 1):

I've resolved a lot of binding statement format issues by using single ticks when using something complex inside.

Instead of

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="mscom" TagName="Wedcs" Src="<%$ this.GetSharedFileUrl("controls/tracking/Wedcs.ascx")%>" %>
```

You might try

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="mscom" TagName="Wedcs" Src='<%$ this.GetSharedFileUrl("controls/tracking/Wedcs.ascx")%>' %>
```